# Can anyone explain this solution to me - how many ways to select animals?

Tags: combinatorics

This problem has a solution, but I can't understand the solution. Can anyone explain it to me? Thanks.

> In a group of $2$ cats, $3$ dogs, and $10$ pigs, in how many ways can we choose a committee of $6$ animals if there must be at least $3$ pigs?

Solution:
If $k$ pigs are chosen from the 10 pigs, 6-k animals must be chosen from the remaining 5 animals, so there are $$\binom{10}{3}\binom{5}{3}+\binom{10}{4}\binom{5}{2}+\binom{10}{5}\binom{5}{1}+\binom{10}{6}\binom{5}{0}=4770$$

Comment: The sentence " Assume each kind of animal is identical" is a bit misleading, I guess.

Comment: You should consider cases on the number of pigs, which should be greater than or equal to $3$. If you have exactly $3$ pigs in the group, then you have $\binom{10}{3}$ ways to choose $3$ pigs from $10$ pigs. Then, you have to take the remaining $3$ members from cats and dogs, which is $\binom{5}{3}$. This gives the first term. For the next terms, in the summation, you should take exactly $4$ pigs, $5$ pigs and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Well, what you are counting in this problem is the number commitees with 3 pigs, with 4 pigs with 5 pigs and with 6 pigs, lets see each member of the sum separately:

If we take 3 pigs then we have $ \binom{10}{3}$ ways of choosing these 3 pigs, we have 3 places available and we have 5 animals from where to choose so we have $\binom {5}{3}$ ways of choosing the other animals, now by the multiplicative principle we have $\binom {10}{3} \binom {5}{3}$ ways of assigning a commitee with 3 and only 3 pigs.

If we take 4 pigs in a same fashion we have $\binom {10}{4} $ ways of choosing the pigs and $\binom {5}{2} $ ways of choosing the other animals so you have $\binom {10}{4} \binom {5}{2} $ distinc commitees with exactly 4 pigs.

If we take 5 pigs we have $\binom {10}{5}$ ways of choosing the pigs and $\binom {5}{1} $ ways of chosing the other animal, so in total we have $\binom {10}{5} \binom {5}{1} $ ways of taking a commitee with exactly 5 pigs.

If we take 6 pigs we have $ \binom {10}{6} $ ways of choosing the pigs and $\binom {5}{0} $ ways if choosing the other animal so we have $\binom {10}{6} \binom {5}{0}$ ways of taking a commitee with exactly 6 pigs.

Now you sum each number and get the result.
Remember that $\binom {n}{r}$ is the number of ways of taking r elements from a collection of n objects.